# How to construct a lambda for a custom sort for dbContext used in GridView on related tables

Tags: asp.net, lambda, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a GridView using model binding and strongly typed EF5 dbContext classes in a webforms app. The gridview is using the SelectMethod property to return classes from my EF5 model:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Server_grid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
    ItemType="server_table" SelectMethod="getServers">
```

My EF server_table class has a relationship to another table called user_table. In my grid I am pulling the related username property from the user_table for one of my columns like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Item.user_table.username %>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My select method looks something like:

```
public IQueryable<server_table> getServers()
{
    return dataContext.server_table.Include(x => x.user_table);
}
```

This all works just fine, but I need to sort on this column. So... I either need to ditch model binding completely (boo!) and select into an anonymous type in my query (in other words go back to using LinqDataSource and anon types and lose the typechecking that model binding gives me, sigh) which will allow me to simply add a simple SortExpression property on the GridView, or... figure out some way to do a custom sort.

So I've been hacking around with that idea and have come up with something that might work. What I'm doing is declaring a sort event like this:

```
protected void serverSort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    sortExpression = e.SortExpression; //stash in a global
    e.Cancel = true; //don't actually sort
    Server_grid.DataBind(); //I'll sort there based on the stashed sortExpression
}
```

Then in my SelectMethod, I'm trying to build a lambda based on that saved sortexpression, so for example in this case I'd put "user_table.username" in my column SortExpression property, which gets stored in sortExpression above, then parse it and use it for the below:

```
public IQueryable<server_table> getServers()
{
    var query = dataContext.server_table.Include(x => x.user_table);
    //how do I use the sortExpression string below to build a lambda?
    query = query.OrderBy(SOMETHING CLEVER HERE);
    return query;
}
```

So basically, if I have the name of the table property OR the name of the table relationship with a property name on that related table, how can I build a lambda from that? So if my SortExpression is a simple property name on the server_table, it will work, or if it's a property name on a related table, I could parse the sortExpression string apart to have a related table + property name on that table. I need to be able to parse relationships of any length, i.e. user_table.other_table.another_table.yadday-yadday.property. There's got to be a way but my LINQ internals foo is not so great (any suggestions on a book for that?).

OR is there a better/simpler way to be able to sort like this, and continue using model binding, which I love? I wish I could just use user_table.username in the grid SortExpression property!! Agh!

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribtes collection in order by `p => p.Attributes["ColumnName"]`

```
public IQueryable<server_table> getServers()
{
    var query = dataContext.server_table.Include(x => x.user_table);
    //how do I use the sortExpression string below to build a lambda?
    query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Attributes[ColumnNameStoredInSortExpressVariable]);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Hm that isn't correct. p is of type server_table (derived from DbSet) which has no property "Attributes". I get a compile error "server_table does not contain a definition of Attributes".

Comment: Check if you have p.Columns["ColumnNameStoredInSortExpressVariable"] ?

Comment: Let me give an example, if my sortExpression = "user_table.username" I want the query expression to be: query.OrderBy(p => p.user_table.username). How do I make that happen? Or if sortExpression = "URL" which is a property of server_table, then the query should be query.OrderBy(p => p.URL).

Comment: Sorry, there is no .Columns property on DbSet, so that's not correct either.

Comment: What is server_table? if is it class then try getting property name using reflection like p => p.GetType().GetProperty(ColumnNameStoredInSortExpressVariable).Name

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I'm using strongly typed EF5 dbContext classes. server_table is a class generated from my database. I get a runtime error trying to use your suggestion in my lambda: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(System.String)'. Besides, the whole point of this is to do sorting for more complex, real world data relationships. What if I want to sort on a property in a related table, not a simple property in server_table?